# How can i add a "field" for handwritten text?

Tags: formatting, rules, questionnaire

I need to add a bunch of fields for a handwritten text 
to my document that look like this:

```
Your Name ___________
Your Age  ___________
```

As an example, I can show you the form that I have to reproduce:

[image]

As you can see, in the top and in the middle we have such fields.

Sure I've thought about `_` symbol, but I think that typing `______` all the way is not the TeX style.

Comment: Putting `Name ________` in your source wouldn't work at any rate because the underscore charater `_` needs to be escaped with a backslash, so it'd be `Name \_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_`.

Comment: See also [Questionnaire Template](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11305/3083).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For my exams, I use:

```
  \begin{center}Name: \line(1,0){275} \end{center}
```

It's simple. (That said, I will look at the package that @lockstep mentioned.)

Answer (score 13):

Have a look at the [`dashundergaps`](http://ctan.org/pkg/dashundergaps) package. Package description:

> The pack­age pro­vides com­mands (`\un­der­line`, `\dotu­line` and
>   `\dashu­line`) each of which under­lines its ar­gu­ment with one of
>   the styles the pack­age is ca­pa­ble of. A phan­tom mode is pro­vided,
>   where the un­der­line (of what­ever form) can serve for a ‘fill-in
>   block’ for stu­dent eval­u­a­tion sheets.

Answer (score 10):

One thing to keep in mind is that you will likely want something that allows you to specify the width of the full field (including label) for alignment purposes. morbusg's solution works this way as do my solutions:

```
% GENERAL USAGE: \COMMAND[width]{text}
\def\entrywithlabel[#1]#2{\parbox{#1}{{\small #2:} \hrulefill}}
\def\entrywithlabelunder[#1]#2{\parbox{#1}{\hrulefill\\[-.75ex]\centerline {#2}}}
\def\entrywithlabelraised[#1]#2{\parbox{#1}{\smash{\raise-1ex\hbox{{\tiny #2}}}\hrulefill}}
\def\boxentry[#1]#2{{\setlength{\fboxsep}{-\fboxrule}\fbox{\parbox{#1}{\smash{\raise-6.5pt\hbox{~{\tiny #2}}}\vspace{2ex}\mbox{}}}}}
\def\boxpar[#1]#2#3{{\setlength{\fboxsep}{-\fboxrule}\fbox{\parbox[][#2][t]{#1}{\mbox{}\\[-.125\baselineskip]\mbox{}~#3}}}}
```

I also like to use a `\dynTable` command for automatically generating blank table rows:

```
% Usage: \dynTable{\begin{tabular}{tablespec}}{# repetitions}{rows}{\end{tabular}}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\InitToks}{\toks@={}}
\newcommand{\AddToks}[1]{\toks@=\expandafter{\the\toks@ #1}}
\newcommand*{\PrintToks}{\the\toks@}

\newcount\rowNo
\newcommand*{\dynTable}[4]{%
  \begingroup
    \InitToks\AddToks{#1}%
    \rowNo=0 %
    \loop\ifnum\rowNo<#2\relax\advance\rowNo by 1
      \expandafter\AddToks\expandafter{#3}%
    \repeat
   \AddToks{#4}\PrintToks
  \endgroup}
\makeatother
```

A sample end-of-month allocation worksheet:

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[centering,width=7.5in,height=9.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\pagestyle{empty}

% GENERAL USAGE: \COMMAND[width]{text}
\def\entrywithlabel[#1]#2{\parbox{#1}{{\small #2:} \hrulefill}}
\def\entrywithlabelunder[#1]#2{\parbox{#1}{\hrulefill\\[-.75ex]\centerline {#2}}}
\def\entrywithlabelraised[#1]#2{\parbox{#1}{\smash{\raise-1ex\hbox{{\tiny #2}}}\hrulefill}}
\def\boxentry[#1]#2{{\setlength{\fboxsep}{-\fboxrule}\fbox{\parbox{#1}{\smash{\raise-6.5pt\hbox{~{\tiny #2}}}\vspace{2ex}\mbox{}}}}}
\def\boxpar[#1]#2#3{{\setlength{\fboxsep}{-\fboxrule}\fbox{\parbox[][#2][t]{#1}{\mbox{}\\[-.125\baselineskip]\mbox{}~#3}}}}

% Usage: \dynTable{\begin{tabular}{tablespec}}{# repetitions}{rows}{\end{tabular}}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\InitToks}{\toks@={}}
\newcommand{\AddToks}[1]{\toks@=\expandafter{\the\toks@ #1}}
\newcommand*{\PrintToks}{\the\toks@}

\newcount\rowNo
\newcommand*{\dynTable}[4]{%
  \begingroup
    \InitToks\AddToks{#1}%
    \rowNo=0 %
    \loop\ifnum\rowNo<#2\relax\advance\rowNo by 1
      \expandafter\AddToks\expandafter{#3}%
    \repeat
   \AddToks{#4}\PrintToks
  \endgroup}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\entrywithlabel[.45\hsize]{Month}\hfill \entrywithlabel[.45\hsize]{Year}    \entrywithlabel[.45\hsize]{Submitter}\hfill  \entrywithlabel[.45\hsize]{Date}    \begin{center}
  \def\h#1{\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\bfseries #1}}
  \def\H#1{\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\bfseries #1}}
  \def\arraystretch{1.5}
  \dynTable{%
\begin{tabular}{@{}|@{}p{3in}@{}|@{}p{.75in}@{}|@{}p{.75in}@{}|@{}p{3in}@{}|@{}}\hline
\H{Account} & \h{Debit} & \h{Credit} & \h{Project}\\\hline\hline
}{25}{ &&&\\\cline{2-4} }{&&&\\\hline\end{tabular}}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image: Finance Report]

A fancier performance report that uses boxentry and entrywithlabelunder

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[centering,width=7in,height=10in]{geometry}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage{array,tabularx}
\renewcommand{\title}[2][]{\begin{center}\sffamily\bfseries\Large #2\ifx\relax#1\else\\\normalsize #1\fi\end{center}\vspace{1ex}}
\pagestyle{empty}

% GENERAL USAGE: \COMMAND[width]{text}
\def\entrywithlabel[#1]#2{\parbox{#1}{{\small #2:} \hrulefill}}
\def\entrywithlabelunder[#1]#2{\parbox{#1}{\hrulefill\\[-.75ex]\centerline {{\small #2}}}}
\def\entrywithlabelraised[#1]#2{\parbox{#1}{\smash{\raise-1ex\hbox{{\tiny #2}}}\hrulefill}}
\def\boxentry[#1]#2{{\setlength{\fboxsep}{-\fboxrule}\fbox{\parbox{#1}{\smash{\raise-6.5pt\hbox{~{\tiny #2}}}\vspace{2ex}\mbox{}}}}}
\def\boxpar[#1]#2#3{{\setlength{\fboxsep}{-\fboxrule}\fbox{\parbox[][#2][t]{#1}{\mbox{}\\[-.125\baselineskip]\mbox{}~#3}}}}
\begin{document}

\title{Performance Report}

\boxentry[.5\hsize]{Employee Name}\boxentry[.5\hsize]{Job Title}\\[-1.5pt]
\boxentry[.5\hsize]{Salary}\boxentry[.5\hsize]{Date Hired}\\[-1.5pt]
\boxentry[.5\hsize]{Reviewer Name}\boxentry[.5\hsize]{Date of Review}

{ \setlength{\extrarowheight}{-3pt}
  \def\arraystretch{3}
  \def\row#1{#1&&\\\hline}
  \begin{tabularx}{\hsize}{|l|c|X|}\hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Category}} & \textbf{Grade} & \mbox{}\hfill\textbf{Comments}\hfill\mbox{}\\\hline
    \row{Attendance/Punctuality}
    \row{Work Attitude}
    \row{Mathematical Quality}
    \row{Independence}
    \row{Pedagogical Skill}
    \row{Interpersonal Skill}
  \end{tabularx}
}

\boxpar[\hsize]{2in}{Reviewer Summary {\small (provide attachments if additional details required)}:}\\[-1.5pt]
\boxpar[\hsize]{2in}{Goals:}

\vfill

\entrywithlabelunder[.45\hsize]{Employee Signature}\hfill\entrywithlabelunder[.45\hsize]{Reviewer Signature}\\[-\baselineskip]

\end{document}
```

[image: Performance Report]

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of the document for illustration?

Answer (score 8):

I often use a box, instead of an underlined region, because boxes are more visible, and so people tend to notice them and fill them in.

I just insert something along the lines of `\fbox{\phantom{first-name}}`.

The `\fbox{}` makes a framed box around whatever is inside the braces.

The `\phantom{}` puts space on the page for the indicated text, but does not actually write it.  (To save typing, I often put XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX or something of that sort,  inside the `\phantom`.)

Answer (score 5):

Something similar I used a while back:

```
\long\def\question#1\par{\bigskip\vbox{#1\par
  \hbox to\hsize{\hrulefill}\par
  \hbox to\hsize{\hrulefill}}\bigskip}
\def\info#1\par{#1\hrulefill\hss\par}
\everypar={\setbox0=\lastbox}
\baselineskip=15pt
\hsize=.5\hsize
\info Your Name

\info Your Age

\question Something very lengthy about you

\bye
```

[image]

Comment: Nice solution all around! One tiny suggestion: In `\info` I'd use `{\hbox to 3cm{#1\dotfill}\hrulefill\hss\par}` to align the rules. You also might want to add some vertical space between lines.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Christian! I did consider your suggestions, but in the example picture the rules aren't aligned (save the ones at the beginning). And I have added vertical space via `\baselineskip=15pt` (5pt of lead with the default 10pt font). I remember coming up with this format for a printable form accessible from the internet (save for the font) after some consideration.

Comment: You are right, @morbusg. I had missed the `\baselineskip`.