# Questionnaire template?

Tags: templates, questionnaire

Is there a template available that allows me to create questionnaires like this one?

http://www.ergo-online.de/site.aspx?url=html/software/verfahren_zur_beurteilung_der/fragebogen_isonorm_online.htm

EDIT:

Based on the answer and comments I did this example:

```
\begin{table}[htb]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (table) [inner sep=0pt] {
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|c|c|c|c|c|X|}
  \hline
  The software ... & - - & - & -/+ & + & + + &\\
  \hline
  is complicated to use & $\square$ & $\square$ & $\square$ & $\square$ & $\square$ & is not complicated to use\\
  \hline
bietet nicht alle Funktionen um die anfallenden Aufgaben effizient zu bewältigen  & $\square$ & $\square$ & $\square$ & $\square$ & $\square$ & bietet alle Funktionen, um die anfallenden Aufgaben effizient zu bewältigen
\end{tabularx}
};
\draw (table.north west) rectangle (table.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{table}
```

But now I have to problems. First how can I center the checkboxes (\square) vertically?

How can i make the table wider? I tried to use \pagewidth instead of \textwidth but this doesnt work.

Comment: You can do this using a simple tabular and the right symbol (`$\circ$`, ...) See also this question http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9975/2975

Comment: @Martin Scharrer. Thanks so I was able to create a small example. Just some issues remaining ;)

Comment: @Christian: Longer tabulars can be split using `longtable` or `supertabular`.

Comment: @Martin I have moved my comment into an answer.

Comment: See the similar, less specific qn http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5468/survey-document-class-or-package/118661#118661

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/118661

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `m` column type to center the checkboxes vertically.
If you want to make the tabular wider then `\textwidth`, like `1.2\textwidth`, surround it with `\makebox[\textwidth]{ ... }` to center it.

Here the example code. Note also the `$ $` to typeset the `-` and `+` symbols.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\newcolumntype{S}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1.5em}}

\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}} % redefine 'X' to use 'm'

\begin{document}

\makebox[\textwidth]{%
\begin{tabularx}{1.2\textwidth}{|X|S|S|S|S|S|X|}
  \hline
  The software ... & $--$ & $-$ & $-/+$ & $+$ & $++$ &\\
  \hline
  is complicated to use & $\square$ & $\square$ & $\square$ & $\square$ & $\square$ & is not complicated to use\\
  \hline
bietet nicht alle Funktionen um die anfallenden Aufgaben effizient zu bewältigen  & $\square$ & $\square$ & $\square$ & $\square$ & $\square$ & bietet alle Funktionen, um die anfallenden Aufgaben effizient zu bewältigen
\end{tabularx}%
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can also define the `S` column to add the `$` s automatically using `>{$}` and `<{$}`.

Comment: @Martin Scharrer Thanks a lot this seems nice! I have one problem remaing. If I add a additional \hline at the end of the table i get the following error: ! Misplaced \noalign.
\hline ->\noalign 
                  {\ifnum 0=`}\fi \hrule \@height \arrayrulewidth \futurelet...
l.14 }
      
?

Comment: @Roflcoptr: Make sure there is an `\\ ` direct before the `\hline`.

Comment: @Martin Scharrer Thanks that worked like a charm although i dont know why :D

Comment: @Roflcoptr: `\hline` (or more precise the included `\noalign`) is only allowed *between* rows. Therefore he `\\ ` is required to end the row first.

Comment: @Martin Scharrer ok but the problem is then that i have a unnecessary newline in my last row

Comment: @Roflcoptr: The newlines in a table are different from the one outside. You *always* have a final line (i.e. row) break in the table, with or without the `\\ `.

Comment: @Martin Scharrer hmm ok. I don't that I'm doing it correctly, but I'll make a new question so that I can add some screenshots to describe my problem properly.

Answer (score 8):

Here is my `\question` macro that provides room for a question and separately room for its scale *without* relying on a table. This is an advantage when you have questions over multiple pages; plus, you still can use `\subsection` and the like to structure your document. Below is the macro and how I use it:

```
\def\question#1\par#2\par{\hbox to \hsize
{\vbox{\hsize=0.72\hsize #1\dotfill}\quad#2\hfil}\medskip\goodbreak}
```

Example use:

```
 \question Would you come to another workshop?
 \par\fiveboxes{no}{}{}{}{yes}
```

The `\fiveboxes` macro (cf. below) provides five check boxes where the leftmost one is labeled with *no* and rightmost one is labeled with *yes*.

For free-text questions and answers I defined the following macro

```
\def\freequestion#1\par{#1\par\nobreak
    \begingroup\nobreak
    \advance\leftskip by 2pc
    \hrule width 0pt height 1.7\baselineskip\hrulefill
    \hrule width 0pt height 1.7\baselineskip\hrulefill
    \par
    \medskip
    \endgroup
    }
```

which is used like this:

```
\freequestion Please share any other remarks or ideas for improving the
workshop or this survey: \par
```

Note the use of `\par` to separate arguments such that I don't have to use braces. But of course, classic arguments could be used as well.

Below, similar macros are seen in action.

[image: Example Survey]

For completeness, here are my various macros for boxes, including `\fiveboxes`:

```
\def\boxit#1{\hbox{\lower0.7ex\vbox{\hrule\hbox{\vrule\kern1pt
    \vbox{\kern1pt\hbox to 1.4em
    {\small\strut\hfil #1\hfil}\kern1pt}\kern1pt\vrule}\hrule}}}

\def\fiveboxes#1#2#3#4#5{\hbox to\scalewidth
    {\boxit{#1}\hfil\boxit{#2}\hfil\boxit{#3}\hfil%
     \boxit{#4}\hfil\boxit{#5}}}
```

In the example above the scale is typeset above the boxes *without taking up vertical space*. This is a little more involved:

```
\question The group is a good mix in terms of expertise and interests.
\par\xagree

\newdimen\scalewidth
\scalewidth=0.3\hsize

\def\xagree{\xscale{strongly disagree}{agree completely}}
\def\boxes{\fiveboxes{}{}{}{}{}\ignorespaces}
\def\xscale#1#2{%
    \setbox0=\hbox{\boxes}%
    \setbox1=\hbox to \wd0{\small\strut\hfill #2 $\to$}%
    \setbox2=\hbox to \wd0{\small\strut $\gets$ #1 \hfill}%
    \vbox{\vbox to 0pt{\vss\box1\box2\kern2pt}\vbox{\box0}}}
```

Obviously this is all very PlainTeX-y and I'm not really an expert, so comments are welcome.

You can find a full example on [GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/lindig/3935127350488c42b8cd40b317e4cbec)

Comment: this is a very good solution. Suggest you include the `\fiveboxes` macro for completeness.

Comment: Thanks a lot I tried it but I get the error: Runaway argument?
\fiveboxes {no}{}{}{}{yes} 
! File ended while scanning use of \question.
<inserted text> 
                \par

Comment: to notify ;)

Comment: @Roflcoptr Make sure there is a `\par` at the end of the question and another one after the scale. You can either type it out as a `\par` or use an empty line. As an alternative, remove the two `\par` in the definition of `\question` and use braces for the two arguments when you use `\question`.

Answer (score 8):

There are some fine answers in the other posts. It is always to strive for a simpler user interface, especially if other people are going to use your macros. Here is an example based on some work that I have developed at work for checklists. The basic row is:

```
\question{Is everything working properly? }
```

The rest is pretty much hidden from the user. A sample is shown below:
[image]

Here is an abbreviated version of the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{textcomp,amsmath,longtable}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\begin{document}

%% Set up counters for questions
%% 
\newcounter{qnumber}
\setcounter{qnumber}{0}
\stepcounter{qnumber}
\newcommand{\yesno}{\textsf{Yes}~~\textsf{No} {\Large ~$\Box$}~~~~   {\Large $\Box$}}

%% we now define the questions
\newcommand{\question}[1]{
    \hfill \relax1.\theqnumber\hfill\hfill &\textsf{#1} &{\small\yesno} & {\small\yesno} &{\small\yesno}\stepcounter{qnumber}\\ \hline
}

%% we now define the questions
\newcommand{\heading}[1]{
1.0 &\multicolumn{4}{|l|}{\bf\textsf{#1}}\\ \hline %
}
 \newcommand{\divider}{\hline}
 \begin{longtable}{|c| p{5.61cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{1.5cm}|  p{1.55cm} |}
\divider
Sl.     &Quality Checks & A     & B     &C\\
\divider\divider
\heading{Installation}
\question{Are the fans installed as per the drawings and specifications?}
\question{Are all safety rules understood by personnel repsonsible for operating the equipment?}
\heading{Electrical}
  \question{Proper motor and fan rotation verified?}
  \question{Verify that proper disconnect is located within sight of the unit it controls.}
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

The actual version is a bit more complicated, uses an environment etc. I use a `longtable` as inevitably you will somewhere end with a two page questionnaire.

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean in Latex?

I have already printed questionaires in this simple way:

1. use the article class, no title,
   nothing.
2. use `\Box` to make check boxes.

Here is a sample from one that I have used:

```
\subsection*{About you}
\label{sec:about-you-rest2}

\begin{itemize}    
\item \textbf{Your Email} 
\\
  \small{(The email field is required to keep track
  of the answers. All results will be anonymised when used.)}

\item \textbf{Your Age}
\item \textbf{Your Gender} $\Box$ F $\Box$ M
\end{itemize}

\subsection*{About the Conversation}
\label{sec:about-conversation-rest2}

The following questions are given in the form of statements regarding
the computer during its interaction. We would like you to give your
level of agreement with each statement on a scale going from "Strongly
Disagree" to "Strongly Agree".    

\begin{itemize}

\item \textbf{I found the fact that the computer acted as if it knew me was irritating.}\\$\Box$ Strongly disagree $\Box$ Disagree $\Box$
  Neither agree nor disagree $\Box$ Agree $\Box$ Strongly Agree

\item \textbf{In this conversation, the computer interacted with you
    in a natural way. }\\$\Box$ Strongly disagree $\Box$ Disagree
  $\Box$ Neither agree nor disagree $\Box$ Agree $\Box$ Strongly Agree

\item ....
\end{itemize}
```

Comment: do i need any specific package for \Box?

Comment: @Roflcoptr. @Mortimer: AFAIK `\Box` is a LaTeX2.09 macro which is not provided by LaTeX2e. You can use e.g. `\square` from the `amssymb` package instead.

Comment: @Roflcoptr: `\usepackage{latexsym}` will make `\Box` available

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}
\def\MBox{\Large\ensuremath{\Box}}
\def\xstrut{\rule[-3ex]{0pt}{7ex}}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{1.2\textwidth}{|>{\scriptsize}X|*5{m{6mm}|}>{\scriptsize}X|}\hline
  The software ... & $--$ & $-$ & $-/+$ & $+$ & $++$ &\\\hline
\xstrut  is complicated to use & \MBox & \MBox & \MBox & \MBox & \MBox & is not complicated to use\\\hline
     bietet nicht alle Funktionen um die anfallenden Aufgaben effizient zu bewältigen  
 & \MBox & \MBox & \MBox & \MBox & \MBox & bietet alle Funktionen, um die anfallenden 
                                                      Aufgaben effizient zu bewältigen\\\hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]