# Drawing lines in tables?

Tags: tables

I use the following code to draw a table:

```
\makebox[\textwidth]{%
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|S|S|S|S|S|X|}
  \hline
  & $--$ & $-$ & $-/+$ & $+$ & $++$ &\\
  \hline
  The necessary information was easy to find & $\square$ & $\square$ & $\square$ & $\square$ & $\square$ & The necessary information was hard to find\\
  \hline
  Information retrieval requires redundant user input  & $\square$ & $\square$ & $\square$ & $\square$ & $\square$ & Information retrieval does not require redundant user input\\
\\\hline
\end{tabularx}%
}
```

Now the table looks like this:
[image]

If I dont use the last `\\\hline`:

```
\makebox[\textwidth]{%
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|S|S|S|S|S|X|}
  \hline
  & $--$ & $-$ & $-/+$ & $+$ & $++$ &\\
  \hline
  The necessary information was easy to find & $\square$ & $\square$ & $\square$ & $\square$ & $\square$ & The necessary information was hard to find\\
  \hline
  Information retrieval requires redundant user input  & $\square$ & $\square$ & $\square$ & $\square$ & $\square$ & Information retrieval does not require redundant user input\\
\end{tabularx}%
}
```

It looks like this:

[image]

So how can I make the last line correctly?

Comment: What does columntype `S` mean?

Comment: @Leo: see http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11305/2975

Comment: Please always include the **full**, but minimal document, so that people can simply copy&paste it. It is normally only a few lines more...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have **two** `\\` now:

```
... redundant user input\\
\\\hline
\end{tabularx}%
```

Before you had **no** `\\`:

```
... redundant user input
\hline
\end{tabularx}%
```

which causes the mentioned error.

You need only **one** `\\`:

```
... redundant user input\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}%
```

And then it works properly.

The reason why some lines are missing when you have two `\\` is that the cells are not filled out, e.g. there are not `&` in the last row. The lines are only drawn with the cells. Therefore no cells -> no lines.