# Table for Questionnaire

Tags: tables

I am trying to do this

[image]

Using this code. It does not look good and also table tends to float and sometimes need to be broken. How can I do it in a better way? Here is my code:

```
        \documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
        
        \begin{document}
        \begin{table}[]
            \begin{tabular}{llllll}
                & Nearly &  & Sometimes &  & Rarely \\
                1. When I set a goal, I write it down.               &        &  &           &  &        \\ \cline{2-2} \cline{4-4}  \cline{6-6}
                2. I describe my goal in specific, measurable terms. &        &  &           &  &        \\ \cline{2-2} \cline{4-4}  \cline{6-6}
                3.                                                   &        &  &           &  &        \\ \cline{2-2} \cline{4-4}  \cline{6-6}
                4.                                                   &        &  &           &  &      \\  \cline{2-2} \cline{4-4}  \cline{6-6}
            \end{tabular}
        \end{table}
        \end{document}
```

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11305/questionnaire-template

Comment: I saw this and it does not suit my needs. Thanks though.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "table ... sometimes need[s] to be broken".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With`tabularray` and `booktabs` TblrLibrary:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
\begin{tblr}{colspec={r X[2.5,l] X[c,b]  X[c,b] X[c,b]},
             rows={font=\linespread{0.84}\selectfont},
             row{1}={font=\bfseries},
             }
    &   & {Nearly\\ Always} & Sometimes   & Rarely \\
1.  &   When I set a goal, I write it down.               
        &   &   &       \\ 
        \cmidrule[lr]{3-3} \cmidrule[lr]{4-4} \cmidrule[lr]{5-5}
2.  &   I describe my goal in specific, measurable terms.
        &   &   &       \\  
        \cmidrule[lr]{3-3} \cmidrule[lr]{4-4} \cmidrule[lr]{5-5}
3.  &   I offten visualize my goals
        &   &   &       \\
        \cmidrule[lr]{3-3} \cmidrule[lr]{4-4} \cmidrule[lr]{5-5}
4.  &   My goals are achievable
        &   &   &       \\
        \cmidrule[lr]{3-3} \cmidrule[lr]{4-4} \cmidrule[lr]{5-5}
5.  &   I set realistic deadlines for completing my goals
        &   &   &       \\
        \cmidrule[lr]{3-3} \cmidrule[lr]{4-4} \cmidrule[lr]{5-5}
6.  &   \dots
        &   &   &       \\
        \cmidrule[lr]{3-3} \cmidrule[lr]{4-4} \cmidrule[lr]{5-5}
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

With `tabularx`, `booktabs` and `makecell`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, tabularx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{r >{\hsize=1.6\hsize}X
                          *{3}{>{\hsize=0.8\hsize}X}
                            }
    &   &   \thead[bc]{Nearly\\ Always} 
            &   \thead[bc]{Sometimes}
                &   \thead[bc]{Rarely}  \\
1.  &   When I set a goal, I write it down.               
        &   &   &       \\ 
        \cmidrule(lr){3-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-4} \cmidrule(lr){5-5}
2.  &   I describe my goal in specific, measurable terms.
        &   &   &       \\  
        \cmidrule(lr){3-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-4} \cmidrule(lr){5-5}
3.  &   I offten visualize my goals
        &   &   &       \\
        \cmidrule(lr){3-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-4} \cmidrule(lr){5-5}
4.  &   My goals are achievable
        &   &   &       \\
        \cmidrule(lr){3-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-4} \cmidrule(lr){5-5}
5.  &   I set realistic deadlines for completing my goals
        &   &   &       \\
        \cmidrule(lr){3-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-4} \cmidrule(lr){5-5}
6.  &   \dots
        &   &   &       \\
        \cmidrule(lr){3-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-4} \cmidrule(lr){5-5}
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Do you expect like this?

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tabularx}        

        \begin{document}

        \begin{table}[]
%            \begin{tabular}{llllll}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lp{5cm}lll}
&& \textbf{Nearly} \\
&&\textbf{Always} & \textbf{Sometimes} & \textbf{Rarely} \\
1. &When I set a goal, I write it down. &\hrulefill &\hrulefill &\hrulefill\\
2. &I describe my goal in specific, measurable terms. &\hrulefill &\hrulefill &\hrulefill\\
            \end{tabularx}
        \end{table}
        \end{document}
```

[image]