# Long underscore in LaTeX

Tags: formatting, rules, text-decorations

In LaTeX, how would I make a long underscore?

For example,

```
Name _______  Signature _______
```

Comment: Those should be lines (rules) and not underscores.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can i add a "field" for handwritten text?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2716/how-can-i-add-a-field-for-handwritten-text)

Comment: @Caramdir Oddly though, the simple solutions like mine and Jake's don't appear there.

Comment: @Alan: Yes, I noticed that.

Comment: Perhaps the best thing to do is to close this question and add the simple solutions to the other question?  I'll upvote them.

Comment: @Neil I think the way you've posed the question is nice and simple and captures what many people have a need for; the other question is really quite a bit more complicated, so I think we shouldn't close this one. (I'd also wait a bit before accepting either answer.)

Comment: Might I ask what possessed you to come back and *unaccept* my answer in favor of one that had been around long before I made mine?  It feels discourteous.

Comment: @RyanReich: Oh geez :(  I really didn't mean to be discourteous.  To be fair, I had already upvoted your answer and the other one, but looking back, I thought the underline solution produced a rule that was below the text and that seems better to me now.  I thought since all three top answers  had 10k+ rep, you wouldn't even notice!  If you think reaccepting yours is more courteous, I'd be happy to.

Comment: No it's not the reputation (as you say). I'm just taken aback since its been so long.

Comment: @RyanReich: Ok, sorry again.

Answer (score 156, accepted):

You can just `\underline` a `\hspace`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
Name \underline{\hspace{3cm}}
Signature \underline{\hspace{3cm}}

\end{document}
```

[image: underlined spaces]

Comment: Is this better than just using a rule? If so, how?

Comment: @Seamus -- using `\hspace` isn't necessarily "better" than just using a rule, but if you are placing the rule after a word, the `\underline` will place it lower than the baseline, which looks better in most cases.  so it saves a bit of decision making.

Comment: @Seamus: It also uses the standard line thickness, so you don't run the risk of making the line slightly too thick or thin.

Comment: Use `#em` instead of `#cm` in order to make the length of the underscore depend on the font’s width.

Answer (score 46):

You can use `\rule`:

```
\rule[<raise height>]{<width>}{<height>}
```

For example `\rule{2in}{.5pt}` will give you the sort of thing you want.

The optional  argument can be used to raise (positive value) or lower (negative value) the rule.  Sometimes lowering it slightly looks better.

Comment: This is a good solution if you want fine control over the dimensions.

Answer (score 27):

As I learned from the `exam` class's documentation, you can do this:

```
\makebox[0.5\textwidth]{Name:\enspace\hrulefill}
```

which allows you to control how much space the entire construction takes up, rather than just the underlined part.

Answer (score 16):

A code such as

```
\newcommand\blank[1]{\rule[-.2ex]{#1}{.4pt}}
```

in your preamble allows you to say

```
\blank{2cm}
```

instead of your complicated construction.

Answer (score 14):

If you want a line (or rule) at the baseline of a specific length (and width), you can just use `\rule{<len>}{<width>}`. You can also adjust the vertical displacement (or depth) by adding an optional argument: `\rule[<depth>]{<len>}{<width>}`.

Here's a mock-up using an example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\uline}[1]{\rule[0pt]{#1}{0.4pt}}% Fill this blank
\begin{document}
Assume $A \subset B$.
We want to show $A \subset (A \cap B)$ and \uline{2cm}.
The first fact is true since: $A \subset B \Rightarrow$
if $x \in A$ then \uline{2cm} $\Rightarrow$
if $x \in A$ then $x \in A and B$.
The second fact is true by \uline{2cm}.

Conversly, assume \uline{2cm}.
By the first property again, $B \supset$ \uline{2cm},
so we have \uline{4cm}.
\end{document}​​​​​​​​​​​
```

I've defined `\uline` to take a single argument, fixing the others passed to `\rule` (width is `0.4pt` and depth is `0pt`). You can modify this as required, depending on the preference.

Comment: I'm confused - the answer does not modify `\rule` anymore, but it still seems like it did. Could somebody mark the update?

Comment: @Blaisorblade: Yes, I'll flag the comments as obsolete and request a moderator to remove them. You can see the original entries as part of the [post history/revisions](http://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/36922/revisions).

Answer (score 10):

In ConTeXt you can use the command `\thinrules`. The optional parameter `n` outputs a particular amount of lines. Example:

```
\starttext

Some text \thinrules[n=1]
\blank                                                                                
Some text \thinrules[n=2]

\stoptext
```

The result:

[image: result]

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the `soul` package. This has the added benefit that the underline can be of a different color, and also should be able to work across paragraph boundaries (except that [there appears to be a bug](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24770/using-a-phantom-in-ul-from-the-soul-pacakge), so had to add the `\mbox` below for now.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}%
\usepackage{soul}%

\newcommand{\UnderlineText}[2][red]{\setulcolor{#1}\ul{#2}}%

\begin{document}
    Signature \UnderlineText[blue]{\mbox{\hspace{5cm}}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If all you want is a coloured line, you don't need the `soul` package. Instead, you can just use the `\color` command from the `xcolor` package:  `\color{red}{\underline{\hspace{3cm}}}`

Comment: @Jake: Good point. I have been using the `\UnderlineText` to obtain an underline of a different coloring than the text, but since in this case there is no text that is not really an issue. Hopefully, once the related problem is solved, this solution will be of some use as the `\ul` will handle line boundaries.