# Using a \phantom{} in \ul from the soul package

Tags: macros, spacing, soul

In responding to how to typeset a [Long underscore in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24766/long-underscore-in-latex/24769#24769), I attempted to use a `\phantom` with `\ul`, but end up `Argument of \makeph@nt has an extra }.` So, what is the proper way to use a `\phantom` command in such a situation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}%
\usepackage{soul}%

\newcommand{\UnderlineText}[2][red]{\setulcolor{#1}\ul{#2}}%

\begin{document}
    Signature: \UnderlineText[blue]{Sign here}

    %Signature: \UnderlineText[blue]{\phantom{Sign here}}% Error if un-commented.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you wrap the `\phantom{...}` in an extra set of curly braces, the code works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}%
\usepackage{soul}%

\newcommand{\UnderlineText}[2][red]{\setulcolor{#1}\ul{#2}}%

\begin{document}
    Signature: \UnderlineText[blue]{{\phantom{Sign here}}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yep, did not occur to me to try that. Any idea why that is the case?

Comment: No, unfortunately not. I assume once the day starts in Europe, the real TeXperts will quickly solve this.

Comment: Simply read section 2 of the documentation. It describes what must be protected inside a soul argument and how you can do it.

Comment: AFAIK `soul` reads the content of its macros token (or brace group) by token and so splits the `\phantom` and its argument apart. It has an internal list of macro to officially support (like the `\textxx` format macros), but fails on macros unknown to it (it can't know how many arguments they have). Wrapping the whole thing in braces will make `soul` take it as one unit. However, line breaking might not be done for these (AFAIK `soul` boxes all single units).