# Problem with LetLtxMacro

Tags: macros, memoir, rules

I'm trying to redefine `\rule` to make cleaner underscores, but my book file (in memoir class) is having problems with the following:

```
\RequirePackage{letltxmacro}
\LetLtxMacro{\oldrule}{\rule}
\renewcommand{\rule}[1]{\oldrule[0pt]{#1}{0.4pt}}
```

I get an "undefined control sequence" on `\LetLtxMacro{\oldrule}{\rule}`.

Comment: It's a very bad idea to redefine an important command of LaTeX, which is used in many places with a different syntax.

Comment: It was suggested to me here: [http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/36922/9757].  If there's a better way of doing this, though, that would be helpful too.  Thanks!

Comment: The suggestion was bad. You won't be able to typeset footnotes, for example. Why not defining a command as I suggested you? `\newcommand{\blank}[1]{\rule{#1}{0.4pt}}`

Comment: @egreg: Note that in [my answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/36922/5764) to [@ jamaicanworm's question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36920/writing-clean-long-underscores) there was no mention of using [`memoir`](http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir). Moreover, the example given had no mention of the scope. Using something else (like your suggestion) would work fine.

Comment: @Werner It doesn't matter much what class is being used: *don't* ever advise to redefine kernel commands other than those that simply produce text; for instance `\let\phi\varphi` is OK, but redefining `\parbox` would be disastrous.

Comment: @egreg: Kernel commands, got it.

Comment: `\newcommand{\blank}[1]{\rule{#1}{0.4pt}}` works great.  Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The purpose of `\newcommand` in LaTeX is exactly to protect users from redefining a command that can be very important for the system.

For instance, if one tries to redefine `\fi`, all sorts of strange things will happen, starting from LaTeX throwing an error when finding `\begin{document}` and telling

```
Missing \begin{document}.
```

Really. :)

The command `\rule` is used in the LaTeX kernel when typesetting footnotes and redefining it will break the feature. Classes and packages may use `\rule` as well: it appears 14 times in `memoir.cls`.

In some cases it's good to redefine also kernel commands; Heiko Oberdiek's packages do it frequently and for this the package **letltxmacro** has been devised. However users should know precisely what they're doing, and *never* change the command syntax (the number and nature of arguments).

It's quite strange that you get an error, because your code works for me. However, *don't* use it. Rather define a personal command such as

```
\newcommand{\blank}[1]{\rule{#1}{0.4pt}}
```

You'll have only benefits from this: you give *semantic* value to your code.