# Defining rules for line breaks in \newcommand

Tags: macros, line-breaking, rules, amsthm

Thanks to the help of [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/36940/9757), I've defined a command for creating a blank line:

```
\newcommand{\blank}[1]{\rule{#1}{0.4pt}}
```

However, because this is a user-defined command, LaTeX doesn't seem to factor it in to its calculations of when to start a new line.  For example, if I write:

```
This is a long line and the blank line at the end is going to run off the page \blank{6cm}
```

then the blank line at the end runs off the page.  How can I prevent this from happening?

EDIT:  This actually only happens in a specific case:  when I'm in the `amsthm` package's `proof` environment, and I have at least one line of writing followed by an enumeration.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newcommand{\blank}[1]{\rule[-3pt]{#1}{0.4pt}}  % nice blank underscores
\begin{document}
\begin{proof}
Here is my proof:
\begin{enumerate}
\item This is a long line and the blank line is going to run off \blank{8cm}
\item This is the second line.
\end{enumerate}
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

Even when the blank line doesn't run off the page, I still get an `overfull hbox` warning for each instance of `\blank` I have within an enumerate in a proof.

Comment: Can you explain in more detail where is this line to appear? Do you want a line to fill the remaining space on a line, or a line to separate paragraphs?

Comment: You're right, this only happens in a very specific case--when I'm in the `amsthm` package's `proof` environment, and I have at least one line of writing followed by an enumeration.  I've edited the question to explain this.

Comment: this could happen in any `enumerate` environment, not just within a proof with `amsthm`.  (remove `amsthm` and the proof environment to demonstrate.)  it's still a useful question though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want that the rule goes automatically on the next line if it can't be placed in the current one, just say

```
\newcommand{\blank}[2][100]{\hfil\penalty#1\hfilneg\rule[-3pt]{#2}{0.4pt}}
```

This is modeled on the `\filbreak` macro in the TeXbook.

The default penalty is 100, which discourages a line break. In cases of emergency you can insert a different one as optional argument:

```
 \blank[0]{3cm}
```

[image]

Comment: This actually automatically puts the rule on the next line, even if it COULD fit on the current one...

Comment: @jamaicanworm Change `-100` into `0`

Comment: In the following code, I'm still getting this problem: 

\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\blank}[1]{\hfil\penalty0\hfilneg\rule[-3pt]{#1}{0.4pt}}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item We can write $A^n$ as
\\[ A^n = \bigcup_{a^{n-1} \in A^{n-1}} \{(a^{n-1}, a) \,:\, a \in A \}, \\]
which by the inductive hypothesis is a \blank{2cm} union of countable sets,
so by Corrolary \blank{2cm}, $A^n$ is at most countable.
But $A$ is infinite $\Rightarrow A^n$ is \blank{2cm}.
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}

The blank between `is a` and `union` is on a new line, even thought there's space for it...

Comment: @jamaicanworm See edit

Comment: Whether the `\hfill` parameter is 0 or 100, I'm still having problems.  In the following example, the blank between `$x \in$` and `(for some $i$)` appears on a new line...
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\blank}[1]{\hfil\penalty100\hfilneg\rule[-3pt]{#1}{0.4pt}}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item \blank{2cm} and \blank{2cm}
$\Rightarrow x \in$ \blank{2cm} (for some $i$)
$\Rightarrow x \in A \cap B_{i}$ (\blank{2cm})
$\Rightarrow$ \blank{2cm} or $x \in A \cap B_{2}$
or ... or \blank{2cm}
$\Rightarrow x \in \bigcup_{i=1}^n (A \cap B_{i})$.
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}

Comment: @jamaicanworm Change to 1000. You are putting too heavy requirements to the paragraph maker.

Answer (score 4):

The following example shows the definition of a `\IntRule` command which will typeset the rule immediately after the text if there's enough space in the line; otherwise, the line will be moved to a new line. The main code comes from Martin Scharrer's answer to [Is there a way to measure the remaining space of a line of text?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17349/3954):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\newcommand{\currentsidemargin}{%
  \ifodd\value{page}%
    \oddsidemargin%
  \else%
    \evensidemargin%
  \fi%
}

\newlength\whatsleft

\newcommand\measureremainder[1]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    % Helper nodes
    \path (current page.north west) ++(\hoffset, -\voffset)
        node[anchor=north west, shape=rectangle, inner sep=0, minimum width=\paperwidth, minimum height=\paperheight]
        (pagearea) {};

    \path (pagearea.north west) ++(1in+\currentsidemargin,-1in-\topmargin-\headheight-\headsep)
        node[anchor=north west, shape=rectangle, inner sep=0, minimum width=\textwidth, minimum height=\textheight]
        (textarea) {};

    % Measure distance to right text border
    \path let \p0 = (0,0), \p1 = (textarea.east) in
        [/utils/exec={\pgfmathsetlength#1{\x1-\x0}\global#1=#1}];

\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\newcommand\IntRule[1]{%
  \measureremainder\whatsleft%
  \ifthenelse{\lengthtest{\the\whatsleft<#1}}{\mbox{}\\}{}\rule{#1}{0.4pt}}

\begin{document}

This is a long line and the blank line at the end is not going to run off\IntRule{6cm}

This is a short line \IntRule{6cm}

This is a long line and the blank line at the end is not going to run off\IntRule{1cm}

This is a short line \IntRule{\textwidth}

\begin{proof}
Here is my proof:
\begin{enumerate}
\item This is a long line and the black line is not going to run off \IntRule{8cm}
\item This is the second line.
\end{enumerate}
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This works, but might there be a simpler solution?

Answer (score 3):

The [`linegoal` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/linegoal) provides the `\linegoal` dimension which gives the remaining length of a line. Taking @Gonzalo's answer as a start, here's a shorter alternative:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsthm
\usepackage{linegoal}% http://ctan.org/pkg/linegoal
\usepackage{ifthen}% http://ctan.org/pkg/ifthen

\newlength{\remainder}
\newcommand{\blank}[1]{%
  \setlength{\remainder}{\linegoal}% Store remaining line dimension
  \ifthenelse{\lengthtest{\the\remainder<#1}}{\mbox{}\\}{}\rule{#1}{0.4pt}}

\begin{document}

This is a long line and the blank line at the end is not going to run off\blank{6cm}

This is a short line \blank{6cm}

This is a long line and the blank line at the end is not going to run off\blank{1cm}

This is a short line \blank{\textwidth}

\begin{proof}
Here is my proof:
\begin{enumerate}
\item This is a long line and the black line is not going to run off \blank{8cm}
\item This is the second line.
\end{enumerate}
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

Since `linegoal` ultimately uses [`zref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/zref), you need to compile a couple of times (at least twice, maybe three times) for the `savepos` module's PDF labels to "settle".