# How do I get that line that represents a repeating author in a bibliography or works cited page?

Tags: bibliographies, rules

As I understand it, when there are several bibliographic entries from the same author, you represent all subsequent entries with a line, like this:

```
\bibent
Nietzsche, Friedrich, and Walter A. Kaufmann. \emph{The Gay Science: With a Prelude in Rhymes and an Appendix of Songs}. New York: Vintage Books, 1974. Print. 

\bibent
------. \emph{The Portable Nietzsche}. New York: Penguin Books, 1976. Print.
```

Where the ------. represents the fact that this book has the same author as the previous book listed.

The six hyphens here get rendered as two em-dashes, which is OK, but I still feel like there's a better way to do this natively.

Comment: Two dashes seem odd to me, one dash is much more common IMO (in German en-dashes are the norm; I know that em-dashes are often used in English, but I think they're ugly). Anyway: I'm not sure what you're actually asking. Since you write your bibliography basically by hand, your way is the naturals one. There is, of course, the possibility to use a bibliography style which does this for (`biblatex` for example offers this), but since you don't seem to use `bibtex` et al. this isn't really an option for you.

Comment: See this question: [Long underscore in LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/24766/2693).

Comment: If you use `amsrefs`, you get them for free;); if you *don't* want them, use package option `nobysame` then.

Answer (score 10):

in ams document classes, this is implemented with the command `\bysame`:

```
\def\bysame{\leavevmode\hbox to3em{\hrulefill}\thinspace}
```

the command name is self-explanatory, and is used by both `amsrefs` and the `ams*.bst` files. for traditions other than that common to u.s. math publishers, the length and position of the rule could easily be changed to something else.

Comment: I just noticed you already provided the 3em solution. For some reason I hadn't noticed it. I still decide to keep my solution because it explains how to have `biblatex` insert the symbol. (Also it provides a reference about the goodness of the 3em-dash.)

Answer (score 8):

In [Bringhurst, p 80], Robert Bringhurst recommends that you use a 3em long dash for repeating authors. I've the following shows how to get it with `biblatex`. This code was used to produce the bibliography of *[LaTeX and Friends](http://www.springer.com/computer/media+design/book/978-3-642-23815-4)*.

```
\usepackage[style=authoryear,
            useprefix=true,
            block=space,
            language=british]{biblatex}
\renewcommand*{\bibopenparen}{[}
\renewcommand*{\bibcloseparen}{]}
\renewcommand*{\finalandcomma}{,}
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{, and~}
 % 3em long dash: recommended by Bringhurst, p 80.
\renewcommand*\bibnamedash{\rule[0.48ex]{3em}{0.14ex}\space}
```

The following illustrates what you get with this:

[image: Sample bibliography output]
<sub>(source: [ucc.ie](http://csweb.ucc.ie/~dongen/TeX-SX/11--12/3em-dash.png))</sub>

Please note that some typefaces may have dashes with fancy endings; they're definitely not rectangularly shaped. For typefaces like this you may have to put in a bit more work to get similar kinds of 3em-dashes.

```
@book{Bringhurst,
  author     = {Bringhurst, Robert},
  title      = {The Elements of Typographic Style},
  shorttitle = {Elements of Typographic Style},
  version    = {3.2},
  publisher  = {Hartley \&\ Marks},
  year       = {2008},
  isbn       = {0-988179-206-3},
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The `authoryear`, `authortitle`, and `verbose` style families of the [`biblatex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) package feature a  dash for repeating authors by default; this may be turned off by using the `dashed=false` option.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{Hor98,
  author = {Hornby, Nick},
  year = {1998},
  title = {About a boy},
}
@misc{Hor13,
  author = {Hornby, Nick},
  year = {2013},
  title = {More about the boy},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\nocite{*}

\begin{document}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'll post this as a complement for people using package `abntex2cite`.

In this case, you can specify the following option:

```
abnt-repeated-author-omit=yes
```

This will result in the desired underscored line when there's more than one reference from the same author, according to ABNT norms (Brazilian organisation of standards).

As seen on: http://bay.uchicago.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/abntex2/doc/abntex2cite.pdf (page 14)