# Two Consecutive Bibtex entries with same authornames

Tags: bibtex, ieeetran

I am using the IEEETran document class along with bib style.

I have two consecutive bibtex entries with same authors, although different article titles and different journals. When I cite them, they appear next to each other in the list of references at the end of the document.

The strange behaviour is the first of these two is appearing perfectly as expected. For the second one, all I get in place of author names is, "_______".

I tried cutting my first reference off and in that case the second one appears perfectly again.

Is this a common behaviour for bibtex to omit the author names if two consecutive items have the same string for that field?

Comment: Related: [How do I get that line that represents a repeating author in a bibliography or works cited page?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39071/5764)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's the default behavior for `IEEETran`. If you don't like it, without loosing the `IEEETran` specifications, you have to add the following entry in your `.bib` file:

```
@IEEEtranBSTCTL{IEEEexample:BSTcontrol,
CTLdash_repeated_names = "no"
}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@IEEEtranBSTCTL{IEEEexample:BSTcontrol,
CTLdash_repeated_names = "no"
}

@article{art1,
author={An Author},
title={Journal article},
year=2000,
journal={Journal of nothingness},
volume=2,
pages={1-2}
}

@article{art2,
author={An Author},
title={Another journal article},
year=2001,
journal={Journal of nothingness},
volume=2,
pages={1-2}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I did not know that is a normal behaviour and was wondering whether some problem with my compilation or code.

Comment: @Barman You're welcome. Thanks for accecting the answer.