# How to leave underscored white space?

Tags: formatting, rules, text-decorations

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Long underscore in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24766/long-underscore-in-latex)

I am not even sure if there isn't a proper typographical term for this thing. I use it for a questionnaire, where I have questions like:

> I have worked ____ years in this job position

If I write the questionnaire in Word, I can use 3-4 underscores in row, and it will appear to be an uninterrupted horizontal line in the middle of the sentence. But if I try the same thing in LaTeX, I get discrete underscores, which look ugly.

There must be a better way to do this. What can I use?

Comment: `\makebox[2cm]{\hrulefill}` (use the dimension you want instead of `2cm`)

Comment: See [Long underscore in LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24766/long-underscore-in-latex) in the "Related" sidebar.

Comment: @rumtscho Use the answer to the second question mentioned by Mike