# What is the code for creating a space for the name and date for a child's worksheet?

Tags: formatting, rules, text-decorations

For example I want my worksheet to look like this:

```
Name: ____________
Date: ____________

                                   Vowels and Consonants
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Does [Long underscore in LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24766) help? If so, this question is likely to be marked as a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

Try a `\rule`, which is a pretty simple method to draw a horizontal line:

```
Name: \rule{0.25\linewidth}{\linethickness}
Date: \rule{0.25\linewidth}{\linethickness}
```

If you want to be more fancy with alignment (so the text of Name and Date is aligned at the colon and the lines are even) you can use the `tabular` environment:

```
\begin{tabular}{rl}
Name:  & \rule{0.25\linewidth}{\linethickness} \\ 
Date:  & \rule{0.25\linewidth}{\linethickness} \\ 
\end{tabular}
```

Here's a complete example document making what I'd consider a decent beginning to a worksheet:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\begin{document}


\noindent
\begin{tabular}{rl}
Name:   & \rule{0.35\linewidth}{\linethickness} \\ 
        & \\
Date:   & \rule{0.35\linewidth}{\linethickness} \\ 
\end{tabular} 

\vspace{3em}

\begin{center}
Vowels and Consonants 
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

A different approach, use `\hrulefill` to fill the rest of the line with a rule. You can also enclose both fields in a `\parbox` to control the width of the line, as in:

```
\parbox{6cm}{
Name: \hrulefill\par
Address: \hrulefill\par
}
```

This has the advantage of both rules ending at the same point, even if they have different lengths as in this example.

[image: Result]